# recv blocking on Perl even though socket is non blocking

Tags: perl, sockets

I have created a socket like this in perl in a daemon

```
IO::Socket::INET->new(LocalPort => $port,
                      Proto => 'udp',Blocking => '0') or die "socket: $@";
```

on a Linux machine

The socket behaves like non blocking socket as expected during a recv call as expected
`$sock->recv($message, 128);`.

However, I am consistently observing that when the VIFs on eth0 are reconfigured while the daemon is running and receiving data, then the recv call starts blocking.

This is a very perplexing issue. I did `$sock->recv($message, 128, MSG_DONTWAIT);` and the recv call becomes non blocking.

I have googled but could not see what is the suggested way for using UDP non blocking sockets.

Comment: I have removed "not" from the title because I think that is what you intended (it did not make sense the original way)

Comment: Can you try running a test case under `strace` to catch it in the act?  The fact that you see it correlating with changes to the interface implies that this might be a kernel bug.

Answer (score 4):

First, the literal answer:

```
# Portable turn-off-blocking code, stolen from POE::Wheel::SocketFactory.
sub _stop_blocking {
    my $socket_handle = shift;

    # Do it the Win32 way.
    if ($^O eq 'MSWin32') {
        my $set_it = "1";
        # 126 is FIONBIO (some docs say 0x7F << 16)
        # (0x5421 on my Linux 2.4.25 ?!)
        ioctl($socket_handle,0x80000000 | (4 << 16) | (ord('f') << 8) | 126,$set_it) or die "can't ioctl(): $!\n";
    }

    # Do it the way everyone else does.
    else {
        my $flags = fcntl($socket_handle, F_GETFL, 0) or die "can't getfl(): $!\n";
        $flags = fcntl($socket_handle, F_SETFL, $flags | O_NONBLOCK) or die "can't setfl(): $!\n";
    }
}
```

However, I strongly suggest you to use [AnyEvent::Handle](https://metacpan.org/module/AnyEvent%3a%3aHandle)!

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, it's great! In one hand, you gave me a quick functional solution to something I needed to code quickly. In the other hand, you also gave me an excellent module to learn about, which will change what I did in the long term. :-)