# What could cause a non-blocking socket to block on `recv`?

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, tcp, blocking

I have a TCP/IP socket set to non-blocking that is blocking anyway. The socket is only referenced in one thread. This code works on Windows (with a few call substitutions) but not on Linux. I have code that looks like this (Don't mind the C-style casts -- this was written long ago. Also, I trimmed it up a bit, so let me know if I accidentally trimmed off a step. Chances are that I'm actually doing that step. The actual code is on another computer, so I can't copy-paste.):

```
// In the real code, these are class members. I'm not bonkers
int mSocket;
sockaddr_in mAddress;

void CreateSocket(
    unsigned int ipAddress,
    unsigned short port)
{        
    // Omitting my error checking in this question for brevity because everything comes back valid
    mSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);  // Not -1

    int oldFlags = fctnl(mSocket, F_GETFL, 0);  // Not -1
    fcntl(mSocket, F_SETFL, oldFlags | O_NONBLOCK);  // Not -1

    mAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    mAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = ipAddress;  // address is valid
    mAddress.sin_port = htons((u_short)port);  // port is not 0 and allowed on firewall
    memset(mAddress.sin_zero, 0, sizeof(mAddress.sin_zero));

    // <Connect attempt loop starts here>
    connect(mSocket, (sockaddr*)&mAddress, sizeof(mAddress));  // Not -1 to exit loop
    // <Connect attempt loop ends here>
    // Connection is now successful ('connect' returned a value other than -1)
}

// ... Stuff happens ...

// ... Then this is called because 'select' call shows read data available ...
void AttemptReceive(
    MyReturnBufferTypeThatsNotImportant &returnedBytes)
{
    // Read socket
    const size_t bufferSize = 4096;
    char buffer[bufferSize];
    int result = 0;

    do {
        // Debugging code: sanity checks
        int socketFlags = fcntl(mSocket, F_GETFL, 0);  // Not -1
        printf("result=%d\n", result);
        printf("O_NONBLOCK? %d\n", socketFlags & O_NONBLOCK);  // Always prints "O_NONBLOCK? 2048"

        result = recv(mSocket, buffer, bufferSize, 0);  // NEVER -1 or 0 after hundreds to thousands of calls, then suddenly blocks

        // ... Save off and package read data into user format for output to caller ...
    } while (result == bufferSize);
}
```

I believe, because AttemptReceive is called in response to select, that the socket just happens to contain exactly a number of bytes equal to a multiple of the buffer size (4096). I've somewhat confirmed this with the printf statements, so it never blocks on the first loop-through. Every time this bug happens, the last two lines to get printed before the thread blocks are:

```
result=4096
O_NONBLOCK? 2048
```

Changing the `recv` line to `recv(mSocket, buffer, bufferSize, MSG_DONTWAIT);` actually "fixes" the issue (suddenly, recv occasionally returns -1 with errno EWOULDBLOCK/EAGAIN (both equal to each other on my OS)), but I'm afraid I'm just putting a band-aid on a gushing wound, so to speak. Any ideas?

P.S. the address is "localhost", but I don't think it matters.

Note: I'm using an old compiler (not by choice), g++ 4.4.7-23 from 2010. That may have something to do with the issue.

Comment: Error checking please. Binding the socket to the target address of `connect()` isn't valid and cannot possibly have worked if the connect did,  versa.* You don't need to bind this socket at all. Your loop should execute while `result > 0`. There is no guarantee it will be 4096, or the buffer size, and no reason why you should stop when it isn't.

Comment: Please attach `strace` to this process, and show proof that the process enters the `recv()` call and blocks in there  (`strace` will show it), instead of, just maybe, hitting a bug somewhere inside the hidden chunk of code modestly described as "... Save off and package read data into user format for output to caller ...", and then spinning in an infinite loop in there.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Of course I thought of that. gdb `bt` shows the thread stuck in `recv`.

Comment: I found this question, but I can't read Perl, so I'm not sure if it's applicable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11895632/recv-blocking-on-perl-even-though-socket-is-non-blocking

Comment: @user207421 You're right, I'm not calling `bind`. Sorry about the typo.

You may be right about the loop condition, but I don't see how that could be related to the issue.

Comment: Exactly. Either the bind or the connect would have failed. I was already finding it difficult to believe this was the real code. So post the real code.

Comment: @user207421 As I said in the question, posting the real code is not possible. That shouldn't be required to answer my question, though.

Comment: Then answering a question about the real code isn't possible either.

Comment: @user207421 That's why my question was worded very carefully. I'm not asking you to debug this. I can do that myself. I'm asking what could possibly cause it. I'm looking for leads, not an exact answer. If I can't ask that here, where can I?

Comment: I am unaware of any verified bug in the Linux kernel, and `recv()`'s documentation is cut and dry. There are no "leads", except for whatever you can show. Again: what exactly do you see from `strace`, that leads you to believe that the process is "stuck in `recv`"? The output from `strace`, when the thread is inside a system call, and until it returns, is very specific. I can't think of any reason why you cannot cut/paste the plain text in your terminal window that includes all output from `strace` up to that point. P.S. `strace` has nothing to do with `gdb`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I would need to educate myself on how to use strace. I verified it by seeing the backtrace in GDB, typing `frame 1` which was the `recv` frame, and I typed `finish`. GDB then hung for minutes. What else could that possibly mean? (frame 0 was `__kernel_vsyscall ()`)

Comment: It could mean that `gdb` returned from strace, and got stuck in an infinite loop in the following code. You need `strace` for this. And it's very simple. Even simpler than `gdb`.

Comment: I think you misunderstand me. It was stuck in a file that's not mine: `../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/socket.S:97`

Comment: If you still think strace would help after understanding this, I'll learn it and get back to you.

Comment: @user207421 P.S. The real code is tens of thousands of lines of code. If I posted that, no one would help me anyway. And it's not like I can post a MCVE when I have no idea what's causing the issue. I don't see how I can improve the question.

Comment: @KeithM: The perl issue you refer to was caused by the socket not being actually non-blocking despite being declared this way. This was due to a bug in the module where it did not do the Win32 specific non-blocking handling. In other words: likely unrelated to your case.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Closure: I discovered the root cause (see Answer) before procuring a proper `strace` log.

Comment: I'm curious as to how you managed to determine that the socket's I/O flags got reset, without the benefit of strace. Perhaps you used some other tool?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Elsewhere in the code, I found there was a redundant `fcntl(mSocket, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);` (with no `F_GETFL`) and I confirmed that gdb showed `socketFlags` in my above code snippet was exactly 2048 (value of `O_NONBLOCK`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`socket()` automatically sets `O_RDWR` on the socket with my operating system and compiler, but it appears that `O_RDWR` had accidentally gotten unset on the socket in question at the start of the program (which somehow allowed it to read fine if there was data to read, but block otherwise). Fixing that bug caused the socket to stop blocking. Apparently, both `O_RDWR` and `O_NONBLOCK` are required to avoid sockets blocking, at least on my operating system and compiler.

Comment: `fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, O_RDWR)` is ignored and has no effect in linux -- you CANNOT change the read/write flags after a file descriptor is opened.  So this is not the cause of your problem -- whatever you did merely made the underlying problem go away.

Comment: @ChrisDodd I didn't change anything else, though, and I confirmed that I'm now occasionally getting the `EAGAIN` error (likely where it would've blocked before). The only other possibility is that gdb lied to me about the value of `socketFlags`, but I already thought of that and double-checked my debugging compiler settings to make sure the compile/link flags were correct. Perhaps your claim was only implemented at some point in the last decade or so. We can't use the newest compiler versions. My gcc/g++ is from 2010.

Comment: In hindsight, I'm going to start putting that fact into my questions... I'll edit it in right now.